# Custom form redirect after login

Tags: redirect, login

I have a custom form for logging in (in a modal window) that looks like this:

```
    <form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="<?php echo wp_login_url( get_permalink() ); ?>/wp-login.php" method="post">

        <p class="login-username">
            <label for="user_login">Username or Email Address</label>
            <input type="text" name="log" id="user_login" class="input" value="" size="20">
        </p>
        <p class="login-password">
            <label for="user_pass">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="pwd" id="user_pass" class="input" value="" size="20">
        </p>

        <p class="login-submit">
            <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" class="button button-primary" value="Log In"></form>
```

How can I set it to redirect to the current page after login (again this form pops up in a modal)?  I thought that I would have been able to use the standard redirect url parameter, but it still redirects straight to /wp-admin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try adding a hidden input field which has the value of the current page where the modal is triggered. Just add the following code below inside the form.

```
<input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="'<?php echo site_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );?>" />
```